# Why is only half of my tuple being read when I am trying to input it into a treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

[tkinter treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjJQm.png)

[my tuple list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2u2wJ.png)

Based on my image "my tuple list" and the image "Tkinter treeview" for some reason it does not display the company name in one column and the value in the second column. I can't figure out the error. Any help is appreciated

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
from function4 import *

root = tk.Tk()

treeView = ttk.Treeview(root)
# set up the columns and headings
# In reality "Member ID" would be exported from the database
treeView["columns"] = ["CompanyName", "AwardedAmount"]
treeView["show"] = "headings"
treeView.heading("CompanyName", text="Company Name")
treeView.heading("AwardedAmount", text="Awarded Amount")
treeView.grid(columnspan=2)


# Add content using (where index is the position/row of the treeview)
# iid is the item index (used to access a specific element in the treeview)
# you can set iid to be equal to the index
tuples = reg_company_award(supplierNameList, companyNameList, awardList)


index = iid = 0
for values in tuples:
    print values
    treeView.insert("", 'end', values=values)
    index = iid = index + 1

root.mainloop()
```

Based on the image "my tuple list" the expected output on the treeview should show the company name on one column and the value on the other column. But the current tree view is as shown on the image "tkinter treeview"

Comment: [Edit] your question and show  the output of **ONE** `print values`. PLEASE, no IMAGE!

Answer (score 0):

Your `reg_company_award(supplierNameList, companyNameList, awardList)` seem to return only a list or tuple of strings.

When your `tuples` variable contains values are tuples indeed...

```
tuples = (('388 PTE LTD.', 0.0), ('3M TECHNOLOGIES PTE LTD.', 3245234.2))
```

the result you would expect appears in the window.

And when `tuples` is just a list/tuple of stings...

```
tuples = ('388 PTE LTD.', '3M TECHNOLOGIES PTE LTD.')
```

the pattern you attached on the screenshot appears.

You should fix the return value of your `reg_company_award` function/method.

(also next time please provide some data instead of an image)